# Nvidia driver not working (Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension). )

Tags: drivers, nvidia

So I did a fresh install of KDE neon (which runs on top of the latest LTS version of Ubuntu (16.04), hence my question here).

And I was trying to get the nvidia driver working but so far, I had a few steps forwards but still no success, so here is the process I underwent so far

```
lspci -v | grep VGA
```

gave me as output that I'm currently using my intel integrated graphics.

But I want nvidia so I found this [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers?noredirect=1&lq=1), and did that which involved these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

However, when I ran nvidia-settings I got almost the same error as this post [Ubuntu 14.04 can't get nvidia-prime working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477553/ubuntu-14-04-cant-get-nvidia-prime-working)

```
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
have been installed along with this driver at 
/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

The solution that this post mentioned didn't work for me,

so I tried something else. I went into the /usr/share and noticed there were 3 nvidia folders, one called nvidia, the other nvidia-375 and the last nvidia-prime. But only the nvidia folder was empty and the profiles-key-documentation and rc files were inside the nvidia-375 folders,

so I made two symbolic links inside the nvidia folder to the key and rc files in the nvidia-375 folder, reboot the system and tried to run nvidia-settings again. This removed the third error message, but I am still stuck with the first two error messages. Which I have no clue how to fix them.

A few notes.

-My laptop has both a nvidia and intel graphics (which you've probably already figured out after reading the previous)

-The nvidia-settings programs launches but I only get two options inside the program, "Application Profiles" and "nvidia-settings-Configuration". This program should have a lot more options inside.

-I had linix mint KDE installed prior to this and the drivers software from mint allowed me to easily select a nvidia driver and apply that one. So I did get it working on an ubuntu based system before...

Been going at this for a while now, dozens of purges and installs...but to no avail...

Edit:

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

returns

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0

*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: 3D controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
```

Comment: just ran into the issue, only needed to turn off "Secure Boot" in the BIOS settings and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. A really stupid mistake on my part...

So here goes:

I gave up all hope and tried to install the drivers using the drivers from the Nvidia site itself http://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx . So I ran the installer after purging my current driver installation using

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

However, the installer failed and I had lots of errors and warnings so I figured that was due to me tinkering around so much with that many installs and purges.

So I went to reinstall my whole OS from scratch (even downloaded the ISO again, followed by making a bootable usb drive). Now after my clean install, the first thing I did was install the nvidia drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

Now when I got the secure boot screen after the reboot, I previously just hit enter and went through it...but today with a fresh mind I realised that this didn't turn off secure boot and you have to use the dialog and enter your password in order to disable it. So I did.

A final reboot and everything worked!

Now I'm unsure which of these things solved it, but probably me not turning off secure boot (though after thinkering that much, a clean install is probably a good idea).

I hope this is of help to someone else, spend a whole day on this...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "secure boot" screen?

Comment: I'm unsure if it would be the same for all systems, but for me it was a blue screen, with some text in white in the middle in a window asking questions. (It looks kind of like the old BIOS screens.)

Comment: Also for me the secure boot was the solution to that problem: when youreboot, a blue screen (MOK management) appears. DO NOT use the option "continue boot" now! It will get the system started, but the drivers are not installed! Instead use "Change secure boot state" and enter the password you just choose (only a few digits are asked for). Now the drivers get's installed and the system boots up. See this for a few screenshots: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

Answer (score 0):

Had almost identical issue with the same both OS (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x86_64) and graphics drivers (nvidia-375), except hardware used (HP desktop with the Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) chipset onboard and the NVidia GeForce GT730 chipset standalone graphics card).

Decided to re-install nothing from scratch, but to play around with the graphics drivers and xorg/xserver packages (please, find details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)).

Although, guide from the link mentioned above helped to successfully start the X-server with the NVidia card newly installed, observed exactly the same issue while trying to run **nvidia-settings**. Finally, right after another iteration from the link above, run the **nvidia-xconfig** tool, which spawned some warnings, but created a suitable */etc/X11/xorg.conf* file and allowed to run **nvidia-settings** correctly.

Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for the key problem. The keys are actually located in `/usr/share/nvidia-<version>`. Just copy them over to `/usr/share/nvidia` and remove the version names from the two key files.